# How would you create a dataframe using conditions?

Tags: subset

I am trying to create a subset data frame that will include only 1 column with the following conditions:
Trailing PE < 100

Comment: Please specify the programming language.

Comment: I am using pandas in Python

Comment: Assuming `df` is your dataframe and `Trailing PE` a numeric field inside it, you could use something like `df[df['Trailing PE'] < 100]['column_you_want']`. First it filters the DataFrame to get rows that match the condition then you get a specific column as `Series`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
have[have["<column used to filter>"] < 100]["<column you need>"]
```

Assuming the column you need is `Trailing_PE` and the filter is `Trailing_PE  < 100` you get the following:

```
have[have["Trailing_PE "] < 100]["Trailing_PE"]
```

Please read more about subsetting in the [Pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html).